# What is wrong witht his code:

Tags: objective-c

I have a function that accepts a block that requires a BOOL parameter.

Sometimes the BOOL parameter is not needed and I just insert false. It doesn't work.

```
-(void) vLoadStuffsWithURLBlock:(NSString*(^)()) blURL andPermaToastMessage:(NSString *) strPermaMessage
{
    [self vLoadStuffsWithBlock:^(false){ //Doesn't work here
        return [self arGetArrayToBeParsed:blURL];
    } andPermaToastMessage:strPermaMessage];
}
```

Here is the function it tries to call

```
-(void) vLoadStuffsWithBlock:(NSArray*(^)(BOOL isAlreadyCanceled)) blarGetArrayTobeParsedWith andPermaToastMessage:(NSString *) strPermaMessage
{
    [self vLoadStuffsWithBlock:blarGetArrayTobeParsedWith andPermaToastMessage:strPermaMessage withParseAndReturnIDBlock:^(NSDictionary * dict){
        return [self vParseAndReturnID:dict];
    } withmoFromDefaultSelector:^(NSString * strObjectDefaultSelector){
        return [self moFromDefaultSelector:strObjectDefaultSelector];
    } withWhatToDoAfterGettingANewRowToDelegate:^{
        [self vWhatToDoAfterGettinANewRowToDelegate];
    } andCompletionBlock:^{}];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: I found out the problem. It shouldn't be vLoadStuffsWithBlock:^(false). It should be something asking for a variable.

Answer (score 1):

the 'false' where you write in your code is **Block Definition**. 
What you want is when you call the block, you pass the 'false' to the block as a parameter. 
So, very different.

Answer (score 0):

I changed that to:

```
-(void) vLoadStuffsWithURLBlock:(NSString*(^)()) blURL andPermaToastMessage:(NSString *) strPermaMessage
{
    [self vLoadStuffsWithBlock:^(BOOL something){
        return [self arGetArrayToBeParsed:blURL];
    } andPermaToastMessage:strPermaMessage];
}
```

WuBaoLi's answer is correct. I am just completing it by giving a sample for clarity.